# Missing artifact of wavefront dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

Missing artifact com.wavefront:wavefront-spring-boot:jar:2.0.0-RC1 error is showing.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wavefront</groupId>
        <artifactId>wavefront-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Not much information about your problem, but it normally happens when you have a separate settings.xml, that points to a different repository in .m2 folder. Check if there is a settings.xml file and where it is pointing to.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions from the wavefrontHQ/wavefront-spring-boot repository?  It requires the user to build the project locally, and they provided an example on how to add the dependency to project's pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dependency is not released yet and it is a milestone so this artifact is located at SpringFramework repository (https://maven.springframework.org/milestone/) as mentioned on the [central mvn repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wavefront/wavefront-spring-boot/2.0.0-RC1).

[image]

Add a repository in your pom.xml file and this will resolve this issue.

[image]